# does jquery extend do a pass by reference?

Tags: jquery

I am cloning a element(deep) and extending to get the object attributes...but the extend make it to point to the original object, there is no more a clone. If I remove the extend then it is working.. how do I clone/extend and not have reference to the previous object..
Here is the

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cooolbasha/gyZmt/3/)

Thanks

Comment: What's the issue? Your question is vague, and your fiddle does not clarify anything.

Comment: I don't understand your question to be honest. The code you posted is doing exactly what it should logically. You created a document fragment that contains a div and stored it in `tmp`, stored a clone of `tmp` in `content`, appended a div to `content`, appended `content` to the body, and then removed `content` when the button was clicked.

Comment: Seems like @coool is trying to clone an element and then not have it point to the element that it was cloned from. But I agree the question is vague and the fiddle doesn't provide much.

Comment: sorry guys..did n't point to the right fiddle just updated...check the link now..

Comment: I am trying to create a widget which need to refresh/removed and done over again..so the approach I am following is to create a tmpl witht he default option and creating a clone and pass it on to the widget which fills text/image and once the next button gets called, I want to remove the current widget and start with the tmplate  rather than creating it all over again with the options... so is there any other approach..

Answer (score 0):

extend is for objects, not DOM elements.

Comment: Have you seen the fiddle? I guess not.